# Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects: Issues Installing for 'yourself' or 'anyone who uses this computer'

Tags: windows-installer, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-setup-proje, vs-installer-project

I get a .msi that works and successfully installs the software, but the radio buttons that allows the user to Install for 'yourself' or 'anyone who uses this computer' seemingly does nothing.

If I select 'everyone' I can still choose my User folder for the install. This means that other users won't be able to access the installed software.

If I select 'just me' I can still install to C:/program-files. This means that all users can access the software.

Is it possible to restrict available folders when using the browse button to only ones relevant to my radio button selection using Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects for VS 2022?

At the very least can I modify my DefaultLocation in File System > Application Folder > DefaultLocation based on the user radio button choice?

I have tried Changing properties InstallAllUsersVisible and InstallAllUsers and DefaultLocation in File System > Application Folder > DefaultLocation

Comment: Do you have uac enabled? If not then it's probably not unexpected that these options don't do anything

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Are you suggesting I should enable UAC on my target machine and then test the installer again?: https://access.articulate.com/support/article/how-to-turn-user-account-control-on-or-off-in-windows-10

Comment: Yes, the options control whether the installer requests to elevate privileges via uac, if there's no uac, they don't do anything